# How to solve Mod equation with mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, modular-arithmetic

i'm pretty noob with mathematica but i need to solve an equation:

$$c\equiv m^2\pmod n$$

I tried something like

`Solve[621455041 == m^2, m, Modulus -> 74596505816855975484638389815392741477]`

Is it right?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct.

Comment: Voting to close, as this is a fairly simple operation and thus is unlikely to help future visitors (no offense intended). If there is something more complex that you would like to do, please edit the question accordingly and I'll remove the close-vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
c = 621455041;

n = 74596505816855975484638389815392741477;

sol1 = Solve[c == m^2, m, Modulus -> n]
```

> {{m -> 24929}, {m -> 52367465358866978466157125093802778}, {m ->
>   74544138351497108506172232690298938699}, {m ->
>   74596505816855975484638389815392716548}}

If you want to know if it is right, substitiute the solution back into the equation

```
And @@ (Mod[m^2, n] == c /. sol1)
```

> True

Or, for a more general solution use `Reduce`

```
sol2 = Reduce[c == Mod[m^2, n], m, Integers]

C[1] \[Element] 
  Integers && (m == 24929 + 74596505816855975484638389815392741477 C[1] || 
   m == 52367465358866978466157125093802778 + 
     74596505816855975484638389815392741477 C[1] || 
   m == 74544138351497108506172232690298938699 + 
     74596505816855975484638389815392741477 C[1] || 
   m == 74596505816855975484638389815392716548 + 
     74596505816855975484638389815392741477 C[1])
```

For `C[1] == 0` this reduces to `sol1`

```
sol1 == {sol2 /. C[1] -> 0 // ToRules}
```

> True